# With MariaDB, got error when converting int to varchar

Tags: mariadb

With MariaDB version 10.1, We are trying to convert an integer to a string, e.g., `varchar(300)`. Please see the sample SQL below for minimized example.

The `convert()` function can convert the integer to a fixed length data type `char(300)`, but it got an error complaining about the syntax if try to convert to a variable length data type `varchar(300)`.

The `cast()` function seems to have the same behavior.

**Our Question:**

Why the function fails on conversion to `varchar(300)`? If possible, how do we make it work?

```sql
select version()
;
-- OK
-- 10.1.12-MariaDB

set @i = cast(1 as int);
-- OK

select @i
;
-- OK
-- 1

select convert(@i, char(300)   ) as col
;
-- OK
-- 1

select convert(@i, varchar(300)) as col
;
-- Error
/* SQL Error [1064] [42000]: (conn=284164) You have an 
error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds 
to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use 
near 'varchar(300)) as col
*/

select cast(@i as char(300)   ) as col
;
-- OK
-- 1

select cast(@i as varchar(300)) as col
;
-- Error
/* SQL Error [1064] [42000]: (conn=284164) You have an 
error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds 
to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use 
near 'varchar(300)) as col
*/
```

Comment: :facepalm: Read the MariaDB Knowledge Base, [CONVERT() function](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/convert/) description. Study the datatypes which can be used in this function, and all requirements for each separate datatype usage.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`VARCHAR` as the cast target type is supported

> in Oracle mode, from MariaDB 10.3

as [explicitly stated in the manual](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/convert/).